# BeautifulSoup returns nothing

Tags: html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to learn how to scrap components from website, specifically this website https://genshin-impact.fandom.com/wiki/Serenitea_Pot/Load

When I follow guidance from the internet, I collect several important elements such as class

```
"article-table sortable mw-collapsible jquery-tablesorter mw-made-collapsible"
```

and html elements like th and tb to get specific content of it using this code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://genshin-impact.fandom.com/wiki/Serenitea_Pot/Load"
page = requests.get(URL)

#print(page.text)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

results = soup.find(id="mw-content-text")

teapot_loads = results.find_all("table", class_="article-table sortable mw-collapsible jquery-tablesorter mw-made-collapsible")

for teapot_loads in teapot_loads:
   table_head_element = teapot_loads.find("th", class_="headerSort")
   print(table_head_element)
   print()
```

I seem to have written the correct element (th) and correct class name "headerSort." But the program doesn't return anything although there's no error in the program as well. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can debug your code to see what went wrong, where. One such debugging effort is below, where we keep only one class for tables, and then print out the full class of the actual elements:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://genshin-impact.fandom.com/wiki/Serenitea_Pot/Load"
page = requests.get(URL)

#print(page.text)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

results = soup.find(id="mw-content-text")
# print(results)
teapot_loads = results.find_all("table", class_="article-table")

for teapot_load in teapot_loads:
    print(teapot_load.get_attribute_list('class'))
    table_head_element = teapot_load.find("th", class_="headerSort")
    print(table_head_element)
```

This will print out (beside the element you want printed out) the table class as well, as seen by requests/BeautifulSoup: `['article-table', 'sortable', 'mw-collapsible']`. After the original HTML loads in page (with the original classes, seen by requests/BeautifulSoup), the Javascript in that page kicks in, and adds new classes to the table. As you are searching for elements containing such dynamically added classes, your search fails.

Nonetheless, here is a more elegant way of obtaining that table:

```
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://genshin-impact.fandom.com/wiki/Serenitea_Pot/Load'

dfs = pd.read_html(url)
print(dfs[1])
```

This will return a dataframe with that table:

|  | Image | Name | Adeptal Energy | Load | ReducedLoad | Ratio |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | nan | "A Bloatty Floatty's Dream of the Sky" | 60 | 65 | 47 | 0.92 |
| 1 | nan | "A Guide in the Summer Woods" | 60 | 35 | 24 | 1.71 |
| 2 | nan | "A Messenger in the Summer Woods" | 60 | 35 | 24 | 1.71 |
| 3 | nan | "A Portrait of Paimon, the Greatest Companion" | 90 | 35 | 24 | 2.57 |
| 4 | nan | "A Seat in the Wilderness" | 20 | 50 | 50 | 0.4 |
| 5 | nan | "Ballad-Spinning Windwheel" | 90 | 185 | 185 | 0.49 |
| 6 | nan | "Between Nine Steps" | 30 | 550 | 550 | 0.05 |

[...]

Documentation for bs4 (BeautifulSoup) can be found at https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#

Also, docs for `pandas.read_html`: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html

Comment: Sorry I'm new to python and I want to ask something. The guide tells me to use something like 'for teapot_load in teapot_loads,' does python understand english or is there any for loop concept that's different from other language like C?

Comment: No, python does not understand English per se. The guide you're following tries to be as explicit as possible. You may as well use `for x in y`, x being the teapot_load, and y being the array of teapot_loads you're moving through, one by one.

Comment: I see, also I want to ask about what do you mean by 'javascript kicks in and add more class,' like what happened to the website? Is there any reference of how it works and why my method is failing? Thanks for your answer I think I see a little bit light upon my tunnel

Comment: The page in question loads the original HTML, as well as some script tags, which contain JS code. That Javascript runs once the page loaded all the HTML. Initially, the table you're looking for was given just 3 classes `'article-table', 'sortable', 'mw-collapsible'`. Javascript  runs and appends a few more classes (JQuery logic), in order to make that table dynamic. You inspected the page **after** JS run, and copied the full class attribute, including classes added by JS, which did not exist in the original HTML: requests/bs4 can only see the original HTML, they cannot execute Javascript.

Comment: So to put it in other way, these html tags doesn't have any real html classes, instead they use jquery classes, so the mentioned html element cannot be taken with beautifulsoup method?

Comment: So to put it in other way, these html tags doesn't have any real html classes, instead they use jquery classes, so the mentioned html element cannot be taken with beautifulsoup method?

Comment: Yes, they do have classes initially: the ones printed out by the debugging code above - which exist in the original HTML, so they are also seen and parsed by requests/BeautifulSoup. On top of those, JQuery adds a couple more classes (which are also **real** classes).